# How to make MongoDB/Nuget installation reliable in VS 2019

Tags: .net, mongodb, nuget

It seems like if I look at my monitor funny or breathe a bit too hard, my MongoDB project fails at runtime. Installs "just fine", but fails at runtime with either a 'could not load file or assembly' or 'The type initializer for MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.DnsClientWrapper threw an exception.' when creating a new MongoClient.

It will break sometimes if I switch from Debug to Release and vice versa. This last time that it decided to play dead was a few minutes ago, when I simply switched to another executable project in the same solution that's referencing this same MongoDB project.

I'm using VS 2019, .NET 4.7.2 on all of my projects. There's only one project referencing MongoDB, that project is fully updated according to NuGet, and there are no packages that are installed with different versions across the solution.

I've deleted the package folder, the .user files, the .vs folder, used the NuGet console to force uninstall all packages, re-install them, and in the past I've even had to completely remove the project, create a new project and migrate the code files to get it to work again.

How do I make MongoDB a reliable component in my solution?

EDIT

Steps for me to reproduce:

1. "Get-Package | Uninstall-Package -RemoveDependencies -force" NuGet Console
2. Close out of VS 2019
3. Delete .vs folder, .user files, and packages folder
4. Start VS 2019
5. Install MongoDB Driver via Nuget GUI
6. Start application in Release/x64 (works)
7. Switch to Debug/x64 and start application (throws exception at runtime)

--EDIT 2--

Alternate steps for me to reproduce (this one I just did three times in a row as a sanity check, and no there are no packages that need consolidation even though I'm only removing one project's packages):

1. "Get-Package -Project 'MongoDB' | Uninstall-Package -Project 'MongoDB -RemoveDependencies -force"
2. Clean Nuget cache from VS 2019
3. Close out of VS 2019
4. git clean -xdf
5. Start VS 2019
6. Install MongoDB Driver via Nuget GUI
7. First app I run fails
8. Update dependencies via Nuget GUI (the initial install doesn't install the newest versions of the dependencies)
9. First app I run fails again

Comment: You should provide clear/reproducible repro steps. I don't see how what you describe can happen at all yet and I wasn't able to reproduce behavior you described.

Comment: Clear nuget cache? Clean out everything not in source control (e.g. `git clean -xdf`)?

Comment: @dododo Just added the steps I took.

Comment: @Kit the git clean worked! There's something else that I'm clearly not deleting. The question still remains though, because none of my other NuGet packages that I use break upon each update like this. This is probably the sixth time I had to go through this dance with NuGet with regards to MongoDB over the last year and a half. Hence the post.

Comment: Hm, yeah not sure. Perhaps compare the clean vs. unclean versions of your folder to see what gets deleted. That might give you an idea of what might need to be deleted during normal compile-run-test-recompile cycle and figure out what you're missing.

Comment: if `git clean` works, then most likely it's something about `bin`/`obj` folders. Still unclear what's wrong, but you can simplify your steps at least by just clearing these folders

Comment: if no, then check what else is deleted by this command

Comment: also does this behavior happen if you use `dotnet add package..`

Comment: have not tried `dotnet add package..`But I've just identified (and added to the post) a seemingly sane process to clear things out, while using git clean and clear NuGet cache, and it still doesn't work. How can that process possibly not work?

Answer (score 1):

1. "Get-Package -Project "MongoDB" | Uninstall-Package -Project "MongoDB" -RemoveDependencies -force"
2. Clean Nuget cache from VS 2019
3. Close out of VS 2019
4. git clean -xdf
5. Start VS 2019
6. Install MongoDB Driver via Nuget GUI
7. **ONLY** further update DnsClient from 1.4.0 to 1.5.0. **DO NOT** update Libmongocrypt to 1.2.3
8. App should run successfully

**Further info on #7:**

If you only install the MongoDB driver and its dependencies via the NuGet GUI, then you will get the following error:

"The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.DnsClientWrapper' threw an exception."

If you were thinking, "Well, I should probably update the dependencies". It will fix the DnsClient error, but introduce the following error:

"Could not load file or assembly 'MongoDB.Libmongocrypt, Version=1.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Notice it still seems to be looking for 1.2.2 even though it's been updated to 1.2.3 and the packages.config and the .proj reflects that. Something weird happening here. I'd love an explanation if anyone has one.

Comment: I still think something is wrong on your side, libmongocrypt has nothing common with DnsClient and DnsClient that is used in the c# driver is 1.4 (not 1.5)

Comment: Odd, because updating to 1.5.0 fixes that error every time I've gone through this process. I'm using MongoDB.Driver 2.13.2

As for libmongocrypt not being related to DnsClient, I see what you're saying but I'm not saying that they are related. Just that there are two different errors that crop up, and they are both version dependent, and one happens to work right after installing MongoDB.Driver 2.13.2, while the other needs further updating.

Comment: You know what I'll do a full uninstall package again and see if it works without DnsClient being updated.

Comment: Just did a full uninstall from the solution, cleared cache, git clean, installed just MongoDB 2.13.2 and yup, just like clockwork I get 'The type initializer..... DnsClientWrapper...' I saw you mention c#, does it matter if I'm using the packages with VB?

Comment: VB should not behave differently, but I would try doing the same steps in a small c# console app to ensure. I would also suggest trying with `dotnet add package`

Comment: @dododo tried using `dotnet add package` but I get "The project does not support adding package references through the add package command." Looked up some info on this error and it sounds like dotnet add package can't be used on .NET Framework projects, only on .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. There seems to be a problem with v1.5 of DnsClient. I have solved it by distributing v1.4 of the dll with my executable and adding an assembly binding redirect in the config file:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DnsClient" publicKeyToken="4574bb5573c51424" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.0.0" newVersion="1.4.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: V1.7 of DnsClient does not have this problem